# Chrome auto scroll positon

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll

Over the last couple of weeks or so Chrome seems to have had an update that is making the page resume scrolled down in the middle. Moving between list and form pages on out site it resuming in the middle of the page.

Even basic form pages when you click save it is leaving the page at the bottom so you don't see the standard bootstrap record saved confirmation message at the top.

This is making Chrome unusable for our product demos etc. and causing a massive headache.

I have tried going in to chrome://flags/ and 'Scroll Anchor Serialization' off but had no affect.

I have also tried adding overflow-anchor: none; to the body tag but also didn't help.

Is there any other way of being able to disable Chromes auto scroll resuming on pages so that all pages load at the top of the page. It only seems to be Chrome and only seems to have started happening in the last couple of weeks. We are now getting to the point that Chrome is not usable as a browser on our site when it used to be the most reliable for demos.

Answer (score 0):

In the end we have had to add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
</script>
```

To every page which isn't the best solution but it works.